# Calculate average and write it in other file

Tags: awk

I have a list of students with ID and marks, and I need to make another one with their average marks. main_list:

```sh
#name surname student_index_number course_group_id lecturer_id list_of_marks

athos musketeer 1 1 1 3,4,5,3.5
porthos musketeer 2 1 1 2,5,3.5
aramis musketeer 3 2 2 2,1,4,5
```

And I have this script

```sh
awk '{ n = split($6, a, ","); total=0; for (v in a) total += a[v]; print total / n }' main_list
```

But I don't want to print it, I want to write it in other file called average marks. Final content should be like this, average_list:

```sh
athos musketeer 1 1 1 3.875
porthos musketeer 2 1 1 3.5
aramis musketeer 3 2 2 3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, give it sometime and when you have some answers on your question, you could select an answer as correct one out of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following once.

```
while read first second third fourth fifth sixth
do
  if [[ "$first" =~ (^#) ]]
  then
      continue
  fi
  count="${sixth//[^,]}"    
  val=$(echo "(${#count}+1)" |  bc)
  new_val=$(echo "scale=2; (${sixth//,/+})/$val" | bc)
  echo "$first $second $third $fourth $fifth $new_val"
done < "Input_file"  > "Output_file"
```

With your attempt try following.

```
awk  '{ n = split($6, a, ","); total=0; for (v in a) total += a[v]; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,total / n }' Input_file  > "Output_file"
```

Comment: @GarciSan, means remove any line which starts from `#` which is considered in bash as a comment.

Comment: It worked! I tried the second one of awk, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '{n=split($NF,array,","); NF--; sum=0; for(i=1; i<=n; i++){sum+=array[i]} print $0,sum/n}' file
```

Split last field (`$NF`) with `,` to an array (`array`). `n` contains number of elements. Reduce number of columns in current line by one (`NF--`). Add up array content with for loop and output rest of current line (`$0`) and result (`sum/n`)

Output:

```
athos musketeer 1 1 1 3.875
porthos musketeer 2 1 1 3.5
aramis musketeer 3 2 2 3
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)