# AWK script to know how many exams there are with given text file

Tags: loops, awk

I have to create a header line to organize some exams. I do not know how many exams there have been. I understand I have to use NR == 1 and NF to determine how many fields there are in the first line, but I do not know how to put it into a string.

The text file is

```
Steve   Krause      67  96  78
Will  Brown  78  62  86
Andrew  Phillips   63  88  79
```

I need the string to look like this

```
Name                     Exam 1 Exam 2 Exam 3 Exam 4 Average
```

I am struggling to format the first string without A)knowing how many exams(fields) there are without looping through and B) getting the averages for each student.

This is what I have because I know there are only 3 exams.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f                                                                         
                                                                                          
{                                                                                         
    printf("%s \t %28s %7s %7s %7s %7s\n", 
        "Name", "Exam 1", "exam 2", "Exam 3", "Exam 4", "Average");                                                                             
                                                                                          
    examSTUAVG = ($3 + $4 + $5) / 4;                                                      
                                                                                          
    printf("%s \t %28s %7s %7s %7s %7s\n", $1, "0", $3, $4, $5,examSTUAVG);               
                                                                                          
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++){                                                             
        averages[i] += $(i) / (NF -2);                                                    
        print(averages[i])                                                                
    }                                                                                     
}
```

Desired Output:

```
Name                            Exam 1 Exam 2 Exam 3 Exam 4 Average

Steve                               0     67     96     78     60.3
Will                                0     78     62     86     56.5 
Andrew                              0     63     88     79     57.5
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Are you not sure about the total number of tests taken by each student?  Should that number be the same for all students, or can different students take a different number of tests?  Or are you not sure about the total number of students who take part in the tests?

Comment: If there are 3 exams, why you list 4 and set the first to 0?

Comment: This might help: [Calculate average and write it in other file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56566013/3776858)

Comment: I am not sure of the total number tests taken. I do know there 3 students who have taken exams. The first exam everyone got a 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR == 1 {
    hdr = "Name" OFS "Exam 1"
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        hdr = hdr OFS "Exam " (i-1)
    }
    print hdr OFS "Average"
}
{
    row = $1 " " $2 OFS 0
    tot = 0
    cnt = 1
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        row = row OFS $i
        tot += $i
        cnt++
    }
    printf "%s%s%0.1f\n", row, OFS, tot / cnt
}
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file | column -s$'\t' -t
Name             Exam 1  Exam 2  Exam 3  Exam 4  Average
Steve Krause     0       67      96      78      60.2
Will Brown       0       78      62      86      56.5
Andrew Phillips  0       63      88      79      57.5
```

Note that how `sprintf` does rounding is platform-dependent but in many systems it uses unbiased rounding and so rounds towards even numbers (hence 60.25 becoming 60.2 instead of 60.3 above). If that's unacceptable there are ways to implement other types of rounding (e.g. up or down), see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Round-Function for example.