# AWK script to help format averages of column

Tags: awk, formatting

Below I am trying to have this awk script display each individual exam average as well as the exams themselves average. I know its a matter of where each line of code is placed as to how its executed. This is what I need it to look like:

Name       Exam 1 Exam 2 Exam 3 Exam 4 Average

Joe            0.0    75     87      91
John           0.0    86     72      83

Exam 1 Average: 0.0

Exam 2 Average: 80.5

Exam 3 Average: 79.5

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f                                                                              
                                                                                               
NR == 1{                                                                                       
    printf "%s \t %28s %7s %7s %7s %7s\n", "Name", "Exam 1", "Exam 2", "Exam 3", "Exam 4", "Av\
erage"                                                                                         
}                                                                                              
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
{                                                                                              
    examSTUAVG = ($3 + $4 + $5) / 4;                                                           
    printf "%s \t %28s %7s %7s %7s %7.1f\n", $1, "0", $3, $4, $5,examSTUAVG                    
                                                                                               
    {exam2Total += $3}                                                                         
    {exam3Total += $4}                                                                         
    {exam4Total += $5}                                                                         
    printf "Exam 1 Average is %19s\n", "0.0"                                                   
    printf "Exam 2 Average is %19.1f\n", exam2Total / NR                                       
    printf "Exam 3 Average is %19.1f\n", exam3Total / NR                                       
    printf "Exam 4 Average is %19.1f\n", exam4Total / NR                                       
}                                                                                              
                                                                                               
{ print ""}
```

Comment: wasn't this already asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66606575/awk-script-to-know-how-many-exams-there-are-with-given-text-file)?

Comment: Yes I need help on the second part

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your input, output, and code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this script. You can save it as: `program.awk`. I added `END` block for printing the averages values at final.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f    
{                                                                                                                                                                      
    if(NR == 1){                                                                                       
        printf "%s \t %28s %7s %7s %7s %7s\n", "Name", "Exam 1", "Exam 2", "Exam 3", "Exam 4", "Average"   
    }                                                                                                                                                                               
    else{                                                                                              
        examSTUAVG = ($3 + $4 + $5) / 4;                                                           
        printf "%s \t %28s %7s %7s %7s %7.1f\n", $1,$2, $3, $4, $5,examSTUAVG                    

        {exam1Total += $2}                                                                         
        {exam2Total += $3}                                                                         
        {exam3Total += $4}                                                                         
        {exam4Total += $5}                                                                         
    }                                                                                              
}
                                                                                               
END{    
    myrows=NR-1
    printf "Exam 1 Average is %19.1f\n", exam1Total / myrows
    printf "Exam 2 Average is %19.1f\n", exam2Total / myrows                                       
    printf "Exam 3 Average is %19.1f\n", exam3Total / myrows
    printf "Exam 4 Average is %19.1f\n", exam4Total / myrows                                    
}
```

The input is the file `data.txt`.

```
Name Exam 1 Exam 2 Exam 3 Exam 4 Average

Joe 0.0 75 87 91
John 0.0 86 72 83
```

And execute it as:

`./program.awk  data.txt`

I got this output:

```
Name                           Exam 1  Exam 2  Exam 3  Exam 4 Average
Joe                               0.0      75      87      91    63.2
John                              0.0      86      72      83    60.2
Exam 1 Average is                 0.0
Exam 2 Average is                80.5
Exam 3 Average is                79.5
Exam 4 Average is                87.0
```